# Releasing connections when using PoolingClientConnectionManager?

Tags: java, multithreading, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x, connection-leaks

I'm using an Apache [DefaultHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) with a [PoolingClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html) and [BasicResponseHandler](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicResponseHandler.html). These are shared between different threads, and each thread creates its own HttpRequestBase extension.

Do I need to manually tell the manager that I'm done using the connection when using BasicResponseHandlers? Do I need to wrap it in a finally so exceptions don't cause a connection leak?

In other words, do I need to do this

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(address);
try {
  httpclient.execute(get, new BasicResponseHandler());
} finally {
  get.reset();
}
```

or is this enough ?

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(address);
httpclient.execute(get, new BasicResponseHandler());
```

I didn't see a clear answer in the [Apache documentation.](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is enough and is recommended.

`HttpClient#execute` methods are guaranteed to automatically release all resources associated with the request in case of an exception (either I/O or runtime). When an HTTP response is processed using a ResponseHandler the underlying connection gets automatically released back to the connection manager is all cases.

Comment: This was my assumption, but I'd like to see a better explanation or a link to some authoritative source.

Comment: @Eyal Please see comment to 'Response handling' at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html

Comment: @oleg But that example is single-threaded, and since they call shutdown() in the finally clause, the connection's release is assured. I'm worried about, say, an exception during the ResponseHandler's work that will cause the connection manager to think the connection is still in use.

Comment: @Eyal default HttpClient implementation is fully thread-safe. As long as ResponseHandler implementation is state-less or thread-safe, you have nothing to worry about. Feel free to examine the source http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html#1055